# Как вытянуть значения из локалстора

Tags: javascript

Не догоняю, как удалить выбранное значение из локалстора, а так же как вытянуть значения из локалстора. Есть список, по нажатию на кнопку значения инпута добавляется в стилизованный `li`, далее значение `li` сохраняется в массив, далее он форматируется в `json` и добавляется в локалстор. По нажатию на появившийся `li` он должен удаляеться из разметки, а так же с локалстора. Но вот как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на определенный элемент именно его значение удалялось с локалстора, а так же при добавлении нового `li` и обновлении страницы он не слетал - не понимаю.

```
  var hobbies = document.getElementById("hobbies");
  var addHobbies = document.getElementById("btn-add-hobbies");
  var ul = document.querySelector(".profile__ul");
  var listValues = [];
  localStorage.getItem("myHobbies", listValues);

  addHobbies.addEventListener("click", () => {
    var input = hobbies.value;
    if (input) {
      ul.style.display = "block";
      var newLi = document.createElement('li');
      newLi.textContent = input;
      ul.appendChild(newLi);
      listValues.push(newLi.textContent); //добавляю значения в массив, чтобы потом кинуть в локалстор
      hobbies.value = "";
      localStorage.setItem("myHobbies", JSON.stringify(listValues));
    }
  });

    ul.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      var target = event.target;
      if (target.tagName == "LI") {
        target.remove();
        listValues.pop(target);
        localStorage.removeItem("myHobbies",target);
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var listValues = [];
if (localStorage.getItem("myHobbies"))
  listValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myHobbies"));
listValues.forEach(item => {
  var newLi = document.createElement('li');
  newLi.textContent = item;
  ul.appendChild(newLi);
});

...

  listValues.pop(target);
  //localStorage.removeItem("myHobbies",target);
  localStorage.setItem("myHobbies", JSON.stringify(listValues));
}
```

Comment: чёрт, и правда, не в ту сторону думал. а вытянуть из локалстора как?

Comment: Igor, where can karma be applied?

Comment: @Igor при обновлении  всё равно всё слетает, хотя в локалсторе всё остаётся

Comment: @Bender Вы не показали код, который создает `li` элементы для считанных объектов в `listValues`. У вас есть такой код?

Comment: @Bender  на youtube посмотри пару уроков и всё станет ясно

Comment: @Igor судя по всему нету. весь код, что был - выложил. Кажется я понял ошибку. я сохраняю данные в локалстор, но сами элементы li не сохраняю. li создаётся и добавляется в список при помощи `var newLi = document.createElement('li');
            newLi.textContent = input;
            ul.appendChild(newLi);`
я прав?